# GCC and G++ upgrade to 4.8+ on CentOS 6.7 32-bit

Tags: linux, centos

I used:

```
yum -y --nogpgcheck install devtoolset-3-gcc devtoolset-3-gcc-c++
```

to upgrade gcc and g++ from 4.4.7 to 4.8+

it installed :

```
devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.1-10.el6.i686 
devtoolset-3-gcc-c++-4.9.1-10.el6.i686
```

When I tried `gcc -v` I received my previous version:

```
gcc version 4.4.7 20120313 (Red Hat 4.4.7-16) (GCC)
```

When I tried to install gcc-4.8.0 , from source code I received error:

```
configure: error: Building GCC requires GMP 4.2+, MPFR 2.4.0+ and MPC 0.8.0+.
```

I checked that I have all requires installed.

How do I upgrade?

Answer (score 1):

It was helping:[root@centos66a Stazene]# scl enable devtoolset-3 bash

gcc version 4.9.1 20140922 (Red Hat 4.9.1-10) (GCC)

Comment: Developer toolset documentation on GCC-C++: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Developer_Toolset/4/html/User_Guide/sect-GCC-CPP.html and a tutorial: http://developers.redhat.com/products/developertoolset/get-started-rhel7-cpp/

Answer (score 0):

I think the packages provide GCC in another command not to conflict with original GCC.
Type command below to know commands the packages provides:

```
$ rpm -ql devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.1-10.el6.i686 | grep bin
```

Comment: [root@centos66a Stazene]# rpm -ql devtoolset-3-gcc-4.9.1-10.el6.i686 | grep bin
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/cc
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/cpp
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/gcc
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/gcc-ar
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/gcc-nm
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/gcc-ranlib
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/gcov
/opt/rh/devtoolset-3/root/usr/bin/i686-redhat-linux-gcc